# Ruby seems to have messed up APT

Tags: apt, ruby

I recently added the Backbox ppa to install a few security tools. The packages updated and downloaded flawless how ever now everytime I run any apt command I get the below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        5: from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<internal:gem_prelude>'
        4: from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require'
        3: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems.rb:1348:in `<top (required)>'
        2: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems.rb:1348:in `require'
        1: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:50:in `<class:Specification>': undefined method `rubyforge_project=' for class `Gem::Specification' (NameError)
```

Any pointers on whats going on?

The installed ruby version is 2.7

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/ruby2.7
ruby2.7: /usr/bin/ruby2.7
```

Running Ubuntu 20.04

Thanks!

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. What version is it?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this ..
steps taken

1. Opened Synaptic
2. Marked Ruby for complete removal
3. Marked apt for re-installation
4. apt commands work now.

Its likely a broken Ruby setup when I added the Backbox PPA.